# i got a ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier while using Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, polygon, alchemy, alchemy-sdk

I got this error in the terminal while running the `npx Hardhat compile` I've tried looking at the other examples of the error Stack Exchange but none have been able to provide a fix for my issue.

```
 ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
   --> contracts/MyToken.sol:122:14:
    |
122 |     function freezeAddress(address _addr) public onlyOwner() {
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

here is the code snippet

```
   mapping (address => bool) frozen;

    function freezeAddress(address _addr) public onlyOwner() {
      frozen[_addr] = true;
  }

    function isFrozen(address _addr) public view returns (bool) {
      return frozen[_addr];
  }

    function unfreezeAddress(address _addr) public onlyOwner() {
      frozen[_addr] = false;
  }

  mapping (address => address[]) public transactionHistory;

  function freezeAddressAndAssociatedAddresses(address _addr) public onlyOwner {
    frozen[_addr] = true;
    for (uint i = 0; i < transactionHistory[_addr].length; i++) {
      address associatedAddress = transactionHistory[_addr][i];
      frozen[associatedAddress] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very strange.
Can you recheck the opening and closing brackets for theh contract and each function.

Comment: I dont know but is `onlyOwner()` causing the problem? Try and use `onlyOwner` without `()`.

Comment: @norym That didn't work I think it might have something to do with `freezeAddress`? But I am not entirely sure how to move on from there

Comment: @ZartajAfser that actually worked thank you but now im getting same error on `ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
   --> contracts/MyToken.sol:148:14:
    |
148 |     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    |              ^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed`

Comment: I see.
Can you just paste the whole contract in the code block, I'll try to compile it and let you know what's the problem.

Comment: @ZartajAfser can i pm you the contract code?

Comment: sure @zartaj0 my telegram